# Are elements of equal Props equal in Arend?

Tags: proof

Could I prove, that two elements of equal Props are equal? It seems logical because all elements within one Prop are equal, so every Prop has one unique element, and if two Props are also equal, their elements are the same. But I can't understand, how to express this idea in arend.

More precisely I want something like this function:

```
\func eqProp
  {A B : \Prop} 
  (A=B : A = B)
  (a : A) (b : B)
  : a = b
```

I've read the documentation about equality, but it didn't help me, I can't move from Props equality to elements equality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prove it, but your function has an error: equality (`=`) supports only the objects of one type (It's defined as `\func \infix 1 = {A : \Type} (a a' : A) => Path (\lam _ => A) a a'`). Though `A` is equal to `B`, you need `Path (\lam i => A=B @ i) a b` instead of `a = b`, and then you can use a function from arend library, that does exactly what you want:

```
\func eqProp
{A B : \Prop}
(A=B : A = B)
(a : A) (b : B)
: Path (\lam i => A=B @ i) a b
=> pathInProp (\lam i => A=B @ i) a b
```